# Does publishOn block if scheduler cannot acquire a thread?

Tags: project-reactor

Given the example below:

```
ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);

Mono.just("hello")
 .publishOn(Schedulers.fromExecutor(executorService))
 .subscribe()
```

If all of the threads in the fixed thread pool are in use then tasks are put in to a queue to await being available.

1. Does this cause `publishOn` to block?
2. Can the subscribing thread continue to do work?

What thread is responsible for taking the task from the executor service queue and executing it on a thread?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the provided example, the publishOn operator will not block the subscribing thread. The publishOn operator is used in a Project Reactor context (Mono.just is a method from Project Reactor library), and it is designed to switch the execution context to the one provided by the given Scheduler (which is backed by the ExecutorService in this case).

When publishOn is used, it instructs the downstream operators (such as subscribe()) to execute their tasks on the specified Scheduler. In this case, the ExecutorService's thread pool is used as the Scheduler, and tasks are submitted to it to be executed in its threads. If all threads in the fixed thread pool are in use, additional tasks are enqueued to await their turn for execution. This behavior is known as "backpressure" handling.

The subscribing thread, which initiates the whole operation with Mono.just("hello"), can continue to do its own work without being blocked by the publishOn and the subsequent subscription. The actual execution of the tasks (in this case, executing the subscribe() method) will happen in one of the threads from the ExecutorService, not the subscribing thread.

The ExecutorService is responsible for taking tasks from its internal queue and assigning them to its worker threads for execution. As tasks are submitted through publishOn, they are handed over to the ExecutorService, and it manages the execution of these tasks in the available threads from its pool.

Comment: Didn't you just explain a `subscribeOn()`, but not really `publishOn()`? See their JavaDocs and Project Reactor docs: https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#schedulers

Comment: In today's era of AI, please cite your sources.